# Can dataframe’s cells hold nested dictionary as value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**dict**:

```
meta_data = {
                "attr1":"meta_value1", 
                "attr2": {
                             "key1": "value1",
                             "key2": "value2",
                             "key3": "value3",
                         },
             }
```

then I want to create a dataframe by doing this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"df_key1": "df_value1", "df_key2": "df_value2", 
                   "df_key3": "df_value3", "meta_data": meta_data}, index[0])
```

I got:

```
        df_key1        df_key2        df_key3        meta_data
0       df_value1      df_value2      df_value3      NaN
```

columns 'meta_data' valued NaN.

I also tried

```
df_dict = {"df_key1": "df_value1", "df_key2": "df_value2", 
           "df_key3": "df_value3", "meta_data": meta_data}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
```

I got:

```
            df_key1        df_key2        df_key3        meta_data
attr1       df_value1      df_value2      df_value3      meta_value1
attr2       df_value1      df_value2      df_value3      {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

what I really want is:

```
        df_key1        df_key2        df_key3        meta_data
0       df_value1      df_value2      df_value3      {'attr1': 'meta_value1', 'attr2': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}}
```

a nested dictionary as the value in dataframe's cell,

what should I do?

---

All answers can solve my problem, I picked the most agreeable one for myself, thank you all.

If you have any suggestions from any reasonable perspectives like code style or else welcome to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon changing the `DataFrame` creation , wrapping `meta_data` inside a `list` solves the required output -

```
>>> df_dict = {"df_key1": "df_value1", "df_key2": "df_value2","df_key3": "df_value3", "meta_data": [meta_data]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
>>> df
     df_key1    df_key2    df_key3                                          meta_data
0  df_value1  df_value2  df_value3  {'attr1': 'meta_value1', 'attr2': {'key1': 'va...
>>> df.meta_data.values
array([{'attr1': 'meta_value1', 'attr2': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}}],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

use pd.Series then pd.DataFrame

```py
df = pd.Series({"df_key1": "df_value1", "df_key2": "df_value2", 
                  "df_key3": "df_value3", "meta_data": meta_data})
df.to_frame().T
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try creating dataframe with key value pairs using `.items()` from dictionary.

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

meta_data = {
                "attr1":"meta_value1", 
                "attr2": {
                             "key1": "value1",
                             "key2": "value2",
                             "key3": "value3",
                         },
             }


df_dict = {"df_key1": "df_value1", "df_key2": "df_value2", 
           "df_key3": "df_value3", "meta_data": meta_data}
```

And this will give the required dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for k, v in df_dict.items()})
```